# Macro error when running script with project or library

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to rename my folder files. However, every time I try to run the below  script, I see an error:

> can’t find project or library on Sub and set FSO

How can I fix it?

```
Sub renameFiles()
'
' renamefiles Macro
'
    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim target_folder As String
    Dim trim_file_name As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    folderpath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Converter").Range("C7").Value & "\"
    newFileName = Range("").Value

    fileCount = 0
    filePath = Dir$(folderpath & "*.*")
    Do While filePath <> ""
    fileCount = fileCount + 1
    fileNames = fileNames & filePath & "," & newFileName & CStr(fileCount) & "." &
    fso.GetExtensionName(filePath) & ","
    filePath = Dir$
    Loop

    Dim renameFiles() As String

    renameFiles = Split(fileNames, ",")

    For fileCount = 0 To UBound(renameFiles) - 2 Step 2
    Name folderpath & renameFiles(fileCount) As folderpath & renameFiles(fileCount + 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You probably have a reference selected that is missing - it will appear with 'MISSING:' at the start of its name in the references list. Also, the code as posted won't run due to `Range("")`, but I assume that's a typo.

Comment: Is this on a MAC?

Comment: this is on windows